# EWS OAuth using personal outlook account meet error: The provided resource value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid

Tags: exchangewebservices

1. This is app api permissions
   [api permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUXOr.png)
2. This is OAuth 2.0 authorize URL:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=6cd61515-b6d8-486e-b729-8b2243f85e6d&scope=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2FEWS.AccessAsUser.All&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.pstmn.io%2Fv1%2Fbrowser-callback

3. I can get token using my work account.
   [work account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnYoX.png)
4. I can not get token using my personal account.
   [personal account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I1Va.png)

Anybody know why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/917011/the-given-token-is-invalid-error-in-ews-oauth-auth), personal account is no longer supported by EWS, so the scope is invalid.